# How to update the specific array element index position and specific array of object property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to update the specific array element index position and specific array of object property in Javascript?. I have below mock data based on object property need to update their respective value using spread operator. I am not able to do that because it is nested.

I am able to achieve using below approach but as you can see code line is getting increased. But we can definitely reduce use spread operator. Because in "title" property i am only updating 0 index and in left column only updating the label value rest of the thing is same.

```
   const mockData = {
  title: ["Javascript", "Selected Topic"],
  leftColumn: [
    {
      key: "name",
      label: "Javascript Topic Name",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "id",
      label: "Javasctipt Topic Id",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
};

const handleType = (val) => {
  switch (val.type) {
    case "Javascript":
      return {
        ...mockData,
      };
    case "Angular":
      return {
        ...mockData,
        title: ["Angular", "Selected Topic"],
        leftColumn: [
          {
            key: "name",
            label: "Angular Topic Name",
            type: "string",
          },
          {
            key: "id",
            label: "Angular Topic Id",
            type: "string",
          },
        ],
      };
    case "React":
      return {
        ...mockData,
        title: ["React", "Selected Topic"],
        leftColumn: [
          {
            key: "name",
            label: "React Topic Name",
            type: "string",
          },
          {
            key: "id",
            label: "Reacr Topic Id",
            type: "string",
          },
        ],
      };
  }
};
```

Comment: Does anyone have idea how we can achieve in shorter way?

Answer (score 1):

Then you could do this:

```js
const handleType = (val) => {
     const newTitle = [val, ...mockData.title.slice(1)];
     const newLeftColumn = mockData.leftColumn.map((arrValue) => {
          const newLabel = arrValue.label.split(" ");
          newLabel[0] = val;
          return {
               ...arrValue,
               label: newLabel.join(" "),
     })

     return {
          title: newTitle,
          leftColumn: newLeftColumn,
     }
}
```

Thats how you can even add things to the title or leftColumn array, and still will be working.